# cx_Freeze openpyxl not exporting data to .xlsx file

Tags: python, cx-freeze, openpyxl

I created GUI app to transfer data from GUI to .xlsx format. When running program as .py everything is fine and data is exporting to file 'choosen_data.xlsx'.
However after making exe file with cx_freeze, application is working but not exporting data to 'choosen_file.xlsx'

i read a lot, about Frozen state and this function:

```
def find_data_file(filename):
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    # The application is frozen
    datadir = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
else:
    # The application is not frozen
    # Change this bit to match where you store your data files:
    datadir = os.path.dirname(__file__)

return os.path.join(datadir, filename)
```

but i cannot make it work. What is wrong?

**setup.py**

```
    from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import sys, os

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need
# fine tuning.

def find_data_file(filename):
    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
        # The application is frozen
        datadir = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
        print(str(datadir))
    else:
        # The application is not frozen
        # Change this bit to match where you store your data files:
        datadir = os.path.dirname(__file__)

    return os.path.join(datadir, filename)

data_sheet = find_data_file('data_sheet.csv')
choosen_data = find_data_file('choosen_data.xlsx')

buildOptions = dict(packages = [],
                    excludes = [],
                    include_files = [data_sheet, choosen_data])

import sys
base = 'Win32GUI' if sys.platform=='win32' else None

executables = [
    Executable('main.py', base=base)
]

setup(name='test',
      version = '1.0',
      description = '',
      options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions),
      executables = executables)
```

i tried also putting files as 'choosen_data.xlsx' inside include_files - didn't work.

**beginning of my main.py file**

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import sys 
import design  things
import csv, sqlite3
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import os

def find_data_file(filename):
    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
        # The application is frozen
        datadir = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
    else:
        # The application is not frozen
        # Change this bit to match where you store your data files:
        datadir = os.path.dirname(__file__)

    return os.path.join(datadir, filename)

choosen_data = find_data_file('choosen_data.xlsx')


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, design.Ui_MainWindow):


    def __init__(self):

        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.update_xlsx(choosen_data,
                                                            comboboxes_list,labels_list))
```

**folder inside build**

[prt_screen_of_dirs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hj9fj.png)

maybe this information matters: i copied cx_freeze-quickstart to folder with my app to run it side by side with my main file. Like that:

[folder with main.py and cx_freeze](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p128Q.png)

I also tried to modificate **init**.py file inside openpyxl main dir in two ways (no results, data is not exporting still)

**1.changing this line**

```
here = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

to this:

```
here = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.executable))
```

**2. and adding whole new function like:**

```
    import json
import os
import sys

def find_data_file(filename):
    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
        # The application is frozen
        datadir = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
    else:
        # The application is not frozen
        # Change this bit to match where you store your data files:
        datadir = os.path.dirname(__file__)

    return os.path.join(datadir, filename)

try:
##    here = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.executable))
    here = find_data_file(__file__)
    src_file = os.path.join(here, ".constants.json")
    with open(src_file) as src:
        constants = json.load(src)
        __author__ = constants['__author__']
        __author_email__ = constants["__author_email__"]
        __license__ = constants["__license__"]
        __maintainer_email__ = constants["__maintainer_email__"]
        __url__ = constants["__url__"]
        __version__ = constants["__version__"]
except IOError:
    # packaged
    pass
```

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work", what do you mean exactly? Can you provide a traceback? I don't know anything about `cx_freeze` but can tell you that `pip` is the only installation that openpyxl supports.

Comment: Hi Charlie, I mean main.exe file when run do not export data to .xlsx file. This situation is not occuring when running the same code as .py file. I checked with pip; installed it and tried to install openpyxl from that, but it was already installed, so i reinstall openpyxl, configured exe file once again but still facing the same situation.

Comment: If you make an exe from an openpyxl then you're not using pip. This method isn't supported.